Printing multiple pages of a report that varies in length
I'm using vb.net 2019 version to write a report to printer. Data comes from a database, but has nothing to do with my issue. All code works as one continuous output but I need help breaking it up into pages. Here is an outline of my code.
Here is an outline of my report code. It all works to print one inline document. I need help determining when to set HasMorePages = True.
Private Sub Menu18PrintQuote_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Menu18PrintQuote.Click
    Try           
        Dim WorkOrderDoc As New PrintDocument
        Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()

        If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
            AddHandler WorkOrderDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintQuote
            WorkOrderDoc.Print()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub PrintQuote(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

    'top section: code to place header information onto report

    'middle section: code to place items onto report. varies in length

    'bottom section: code to place terms/notes onto report. varies in length

'here is where I need help
     e.HasMorePages = False
 
End Sub

I am thinking of using a property instead of a variable to keep track of where the printed output is on a page, so every time it is set additional code determines whether to set HasMorePages = True. I'm having trouble understanding how to do this between the contexts of the main body of code and a class property.

The most interesting example code would be the code that fits in the comments you have for "top section" / "middle section" / "bottom section".  Note that there is example code in the online docs for the PrintDocument constructor which seems to do something like what you're trying to figure out.
